# Plot^2 how to get rid of plot entry messages

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

Whenever I go on my plot (I'm the server owner) I always see "Now entering ...'s" plot and it's annoying. (Especially because the spawn room is 4 merged plots). How do I use /p or /p2 to get rid of that? (I also have access to the server files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the `titles` options in `settings.yml` to `false`. That will disable titles from appearing on your screen when you enter a plot.

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't have the annoying messages display on my screen :)